# How to remove Dropbox folder access prompt

Tags: android, dropbox, dropbox-api, dropbox-sdk

I have an Android app which uses its own folder on my Dropbox account. Every time I start up my app I get the below prompt:

[image]

Is it possible to code my app or configure it somehow so that I only have to acknowledge this prompt just once?

I don't mind having to acknowledge each time I change my code but every time the app is restarted seems a bit excessive.

I've reduced my code right down to one line which causes this to appear:

```
Auth.startOAuth2Authentication( gContext, APP_KEY );
```

Comment: Can you post the `startOAuth2Authentication` code?

Comment: @MatPag I can't sorry - it's a Dropbox API call. See https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v2.1.x/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I don't need to call:

```
Auth.startOAuth2Authentication( gContext, APP_KEY );
```

Once I get an access token, I can store that for subsequent program restarts and create a **DbxClientV2** by using that saved token. I can also generate a token on my app's Dropbox webpage and use that instead (which makes more sense in my case anyway).

```
DbxRequestConfig config = new DbxRequestConfig( "dropbox/sample-app" );
DbxClientV2 client = new DbxClientV2( config, savedToken );
```

No more auth screen and the API calls continue to work!